# iFrame Inside a Modal Window Not Working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, iframe

This works on Firefox but on Chrome i am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'css' of null" error on "function onDialogOpen() { this.iframe.css({".

```
  function show(options) {


    // create our temporary iframe
    this.iframe = $('<iframe name="' + (this.id = 'emh_' + +new Date) + '">')
      .load($.proxy(onIframeLoad, this));

    // show our dialog
    this.iframe.dialog($.extend(true, {
      title: 'Entity Viewer',
      modal: true,
      draggable: false,
      resizable: false,
      width: 800,
      height: 500,
      buttons: {
        'Save & Continue': $.proxy(submitIframeForm, this)
      },
      open: $.proxy(onDialogOpen, this),
      close: $.proxy(onDialogClose, this)
    }, options));  
    alert(options.path);
    // since our dialog is showing now, let's update the src of the iframe
    this.iframe.attr('src', options.path + '?modal=true&unique=' + this.id);


  }

function onDialogOpen() {
    this.iframe
      .css({
        width: '100%',
        padding: 0,
        border: 0,
        margin: 0
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will work but I have 2 approaches:

1. Move onDialogOpen inside your show method:

   ```
    function show(options) {

    //your code
    //...
    //...  
    //this.iframe.attr('src', options.path + '?modal=true&unique=' + this.id);

   //no need to pass this parameter since method has same this as parent one

       function onDialogOpen() {
           this.iframe
             .css({
               width: '100%',
               padding: 0,
               border: 0,
               margin: 0
             });
       }
   ```

   }

or

2.
- Create this reference right after IFrame load:

```
var _this = this;
```

- modify this call:

open: $.proxy(function(){ onDialogOpen(_this)}, this)

Update onDialogOpen:

```
function onDialogOpen(_this) {
    if (typeof _this != 'undefined')
{
 _this.iframe
      .css({
        width: '100%',
        padding: 0,
        border: 0,
        margin: 0
      });
}
else
{
    this.iframe
      .css({
        width: '100%',
        padding: 0,
        border: 0,
        margin: 0
      });
}
}
```

Comment: SilentTremor thank you for your feedback but unfortunately i am still getting the same error

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pkxjmv9q/1/ few fixes in your code :p should work properly now.